# django template <img src="{% static "/static/{{ image_name }}" %}" alt="my image"> does not work

Tags: static, django-templates

In views.py:

```
image_name = PUserSliderimg.objects.filter(uid=1).values('sliderimg')
```

This works in html file and we can see the image:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "/static/cat.jpg" %}" alt="my image">
```

But those below does not work:

```
{% load staticfiles %}


#output => my image
<img src="{% static "/static/{{ image_name }}" %}" alt="my image">




#output => cat.jpg
{% for each in image_name %}
    {{ each.sliderimg }}
{% endfor %}




#output => my image
{% for each in image_name %}
    <img src="{% static "/static/{{ each.sliderimg }}" %}" alt="my image">
{% endfor %}




#output => [{'sliderimg': 'cat.jpg'}]
{{ image_name }}<br>
```

How can I get the name from db and put it in the code in order to appear image on the web page?

==================================

I even tried this:

In views.py:

```
photo = 'cat.jpg'
```

In html file:

```
{% for each in image_name %}
    <img src="{% static "/static/{{ photo }}" %}" alt="my image">
```

But for the output, the word cat.jpg appeared only.

===================================

I found the answer myself, I edited the code like this:

```
<img src="/static/{{ photo }}" alt="my image">
```

And it worked. But why?

I tried to show an image on an other page before and I found that using `{% static ... %}` was needed, but here the code worked without using `{% static ... %}`. So can someone tell me why?!